# how NDK build so and link in same Android.mk?

Tags: android-ndk

An Android project compiles 2 so files at the same time. We call him the first and the second SO. I want to call the functions in the first SO in the second SO. How do I do that?

file content and tree is followed:

jni

|-Android.mk

|-myfiles2.c

|-------firstlibdir

|—------|-myfiles1.c

|-------|-Android.mk

|

myfiles1.c  :

```
int func1(){
    return 123;
}
```

myfiles2.c :

```
int func2(){
    func1(); // this function in first so files
    return 0;
}
```

first so file build

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    :=  module_lib1  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myfiles1.c  
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog   
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

second so file build

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    :=  module_lib2  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myfiles2.c  
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog   
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := module_lib1   // this is not work  because fisrt file not build finish 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include firstlibdir/Android.mk
```

my question is how to first build  libmodule_lib1.so  and use in second Android.mk

Comment: Define _"this is not work"_. Post the exact error message(s) you're getting.

Comment: it's mean can't build second so files,because first so file not build success,second so file can't buid ,

Comment: Can I in the same Android.mk   file build  "include firstlibdir/Android.mk " first